# cannot import name 'fpn_pb2'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

```
(tensorflow1) C:\Users\nithi\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
2020-12-02 00:06:04.154976: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-12-02 00:06:04.155212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 48, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\nithi\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 39, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import model_pb2
  File "C:\Users\nithi\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\protos\model_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import faster_rcnn_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_faster__rcnn__pb2
  File "C:\Users\nithi\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_pb2.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import fpn_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_fpn__pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'fpn_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (C:\Users\nithi\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)
```

I have run the training for the TensorFlow object detection model and got this error while training
could not import fpn_pb2.

Comment: Can you provide links of the tutorials that you followed? Its also an import error so there could be problem with `PYTHONPATH`? Did you try anything to resolve the issue first?

Comment: Did you build the protos when you forked the detection repo?
`cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` from [this guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md)